# Laravel 7 Missing required parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

So I keep on getting this error no matter what I do. The only way I dont get this error is by not calling the controller function.

```
Route::get('/station/{id}/edit', [StationController::class, 'showStationEdit'])->name('editStation');
```

And in the HTML I have

```
href="{{ route('editStation', $stationId) }}
```

I also tried as

```
href="{{ route('editStation', ['id' => $stationId] ) }}"
```

And finally the function itself

```
public function showStationEdit($id) {}
```

And no matter what I change/do I get this error

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: editStation] [URI: station/{id}/edit].
```

This is the URL that I am calling

```
127.0.0.1/station/1/edit
```

BUT when I used the code bellow it worked..>

```
Route::get('/station/{id}/edit', function($id) {
//.. something
})->name('editStation');
```

Comment: What about if you declare your route like this `Route::get('/station/{id}/edit', 'StationController@showStationEdit')->name('editStation');`? It's just a shot, because I didn't know that PHP callable syntax could be used on laravel 7 roues

Comment: Nope :( Still the same error happens

Comment: what is the value of `$stationId` that you are passing to the `route` helper when you get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your referance type.
For example, you can describe your website name on ENV file like this:

```
application_url = 'yourdomain.com or local ip http://127.0.0.1'
```

and then, you can cal your url on html like this :

```
href="{{env('application_url')}}/145/edit"
```

and you can describe your Route just like this :

```
Route::get('/station/{id}/edit', [StationController::class, 'showStationEdit']);
```

or directly use your href like this, your IP is important if you work on your local :

```
href="http://127.0.0.1/1254/edit"
```

I hope it's answer what you solve your problem.

Comment: [**Never, ever**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching) use `env()` function outside of the config file. Once the configuration has been cached with `config:cache`, the `.env` file will not be loaded and all calls to the `env` function will return `null`.

Comment: I'm not good on knowladge of  cacging env file but I generally use that and I did not have problem like tha. It load so normal but when I change something in my env file, I shoud clear cache.Can you explain more your suggestion ? Btw, Thank a lot .

Comment: What would you like to know more? The link I provided explain already very well.

Answer (score 1):

A few changes here, not sure exactly what's causing you the problem but this is working:

Route

```
Route::get('/station/{id}/edit', 'StationController@showStationEdit')->name('editStation');
```

Controller

```
class StationController extends Controller
{
    public function showStationEdit($id) {
        return view('edit', ['id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

View: (edit.blade.php)

```
The id is: {{ $id }}
```

HTML

```
<a href="{{ route('editStation', 5) }}">Test</a>
```